# Is my Shared Parallels Folder a Directory?

Tags: parallels

On my VC Linux desktop there is  a 'shared Parallels Folder' with a padlock icon on it. I have been trying for a few weeks to command Gnome Terminal to direct to it. It fails to recognise this folder as a directory.

I have tried quite a few commands eg,

```
cd Desktop/shared Parallels Folder
```

The response is no such directory. Is it to do with the padlock on the folder? I really don't know what to try next. I need to access files on my mac. Please help!

Comment: Did it work for you ? what is the name of the folder  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spaces in directory name may be creating problem try

```
 cd ~/Desktop/shared\ Parallels\ Folder/
```

Answer (score 3):

`cd Desktop/shared Parallels` probably needs to be `cd ~/Desktop/shared` and then {tab} to autocomplete (not sure if Folders is part of your directory)

A padlock also means: no permissions.

From command line:

You can check permissions with

```
cd ~/Desktop
ls -l|more
```

Watch out for "shared Parallels" and have a look at the colums left of it. There are 2 names (user and group). If they are not your name you can change it with:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER shared{tab}
```

{tab} to autocomplete.

chown changes user and group to your name. The -R does the same for any file found in "shared Parallels".

You can also do this from Nautilus:

Navigate to the folder. Rightclick it and choose "properties":

[image]

Set the options here to your user with read+write. The "change permissions to enclosed files" is the same as the -R option explained above.

Comment: When in the properties of Shared Parallels Folder the permissions is owner: Root. Does this need changing? Also my user name has been from intial installation parallels@parallels-parallels, how can i change this?

Comment: @LouiseAvon You might consider opening a separate question for this.

Comment: Yes I think I will do. Thankyou

Comment: @LouiseAvon yes! needs to be your user name. Easiest is to follow the commandline option I posted (you need the `chown` command ;) )

Answer (score 2):

You should use this command :

If its name shared Parallels Folder :

```
 cd ~/Desktop/shared\ Parallels\ Folder/
```

Cause directory name contains spaces

Comment: safer bet: add a {tab} in there :) The name is probably "shared Parallels Folder"

Comment: Alternately, copy the folder name and put it in quotes.